# how can I run/debug Ansible playbooks inside the IDE (PyCharm)?

Tags: ansible, pycharm

I can get some visibility into what's happening, under the hood, by running the playbook with the `-vvvv` argument, e.g. `ansible-playbook myplaybook.yaml -vvvv`. And I can import individual modules into a Python program, pass arguments to them, and step through in the IDE. That's handy.

What I really want is to open Ansible playbooks with PyCharm and step through with the debugger, line by line, to understand the state of all the variables. Since Ansible is written in Python, I figured there should be a way to run an Ansible playbook inside a Python IDE.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install ansible into your virtualenv, or otherwise make it so that PyCharm can see the `ansible` file in `bin`; regrettably, since they have 164 lines of python instead of just a `__main__`, you can't invoke it as `python -m ansible.cli.playbook` or any such nicety
2. create a Run Configuration with the "Python Script" pointing to `.../bin/ansible` or `.../bin/ansible-playbook` etc

   For your convenience, you can also open the `bin/ansible` in PyCharm, navigate to the `if __name__` line, and tap the "play triangle" in the left gutter, although doing that will cause the python process to launch in the `bin` directory, which can be kind of annoying
3. set a breakpoint in the ansible python file of your choosing
4. launch the debugger

Be aware that in a **bunch** of cases, ansible is going to shell out to do things, and to the best of my knowledge PyCharm's debugger does not follow subprocess or its friends, so you'll have to jump through some hoops if you want to be able to debug those style of modules, including any of your own scripts in `library/*.py` or whatever.

I love PyCharm very much, but for this specific case you may be happier using the `strategy: debug` in your playbook and doing battle with the *ansible* debugger

Comment: That's perfect, @Matthew. Very much appreciated.

Comment: With a newer ansible-core, this information seems outdated. With ansible-core 2.14.4 and PyCharm I can use a regular python run configuration with the Module Name `ansible.cli.playbook` and my parameters (e.g. `-D myplaybook.yml`).

Debugging is still a little bit tricky, the second part of the answer about PyCharm's debugger not able to follow a lot of ansible functionality still applies.